# How to improve UI performace when working with heavy page

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a very heavy page using ASP.NET framework 4.0. My page contains 5 tabs(AJAX tabcontainer control). I am loading the controls dynamically when a tab is selected this improves the performance a lot but once all the tabs are loaded with the controls like RadGrid, griviews etc. My page becomes too heavy which causes lagging, slow performance when switching between the tabs. As my user will be using this application on IE 8 I have to code only for IE 8. How can i improve UI performance?

Comment: please check http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html Because using radstylesheetmanager you can improve your website performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious answer - to make your page less complex - contain less DOM elements.
For example to remove DOM elements from closed tabs.